# How can I refactor my code, using multiple useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, use-effect

Is there a way to refactor/reduce this code please. I have the impresssion yes but I don't know how to do. I'm getting my data from my API.

```
export default function Plant() {
    
    const [plant, setPlant] = useState([])
    const [value1, setValue1] = useState(null);
    const [value2, setValue2] = useState(null)
    const [value3, setValue3] = useState(null)
    ...

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post(url, { plantId })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setPlant(res.data.plants[0])
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [plantId]);

    useEffect(() => {            
        if (plant?.water) { 
            setValue1(WATER.find((t) => t.label === plant.water));
        }
    }, [plant]);
    useEffect(() => {            
        if (plant?.sun) { 
            setValue2(SUN.find((t) => t.label === plant.sun));
        }
    }, [plant]);
    useEffect(() => {            
        if (plant?.date) { 
            setValue3(DATE.find((t) => t.label === plant.date));
        }
    }, [plant]);
    return (
    <div>
      <MyDrop options={SUN} value={value2} setValue={setValue2} />
    </div> 
    )
```

Please check [MyDrop and Label code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-shtern-qq443x?file=/src/MyDrop.jsx) here:

Comment: Is there a reason why all that code in a single `useEffect` instead three wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The last three all depend on the same `plant`, so there shouldn't be an issue putting them together.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (plant?.water) {
        setValue1(OPTION1.find((t) => t.label === plant.water));
    }
    if (plant?.sun) {
        setValue2(OPTION2.find((t) => t.label === plant.sun));
    }
    if (plant?.date) {
        setValue3(OPTION3.find((t) => t.label === plant.date));
    }
}, [plant]);
```

If you wanted to be more DRY, consider using an array of values instead of multiple separate states, something along the lines of

```
// feel free to add properties to the below
// which can also be declared outside the component
const plantProperties = ['water', 'sun', 'date'];

const [values, setValues] = useState(() => plantProperties.map(() => null));
useEffect(() => {
    plantProperties.forEach((prop, i) => {
        if (plant?.[prop]) {
            setValues(
                values.map((val, j) => i === j ? options[i].find((t) => t.label === plant.water) : val);
            );
        }
    });
}, [plant]);
```

The `plant` state also looks pretty suspicious to me; the initial state is an array, since you're doing

```
const [plant, setPlant] = useState([])
```

but then you have to check if it's nullish. If you never do something like `setPlant(null)` or `setPlant(undefined)`, there's no need for the null checks. If you *do* do that, consider whether you could instead reset the plant to the initial value with `setPlant([])` or `setPlant({})`.

Another issue is that you check if it has certain properties directly on it, as if it was a plan object, which is really weird. Arrays generally shouldn't have arbitrary key-value pairs on them; arrays are for numeric-indexed collections of data only. If you want a collection of arbitrary key-values, consider using a plain object instead.

Another alternative you can consider is to not duplicate the same sort of data in different states. You could have *only* the plant state, and then calculate the dependent values synchronously afterwards, rather than in an effect hook.

```
const [plant, setPlant] = useState({})
const values = useMemo(() => calculateValues(plant), [plant]);
```

Comment: I 've written : `const [plant, setPlant] = useState([])` because of the output of my json file from my api (see the edited question).  What does `calculateValues` do ? Plus in one of you code you wrote : `if (plant?.[prop]) {
  setValues( values.map((val, j) => i === j ? options[i].find((t) => t.label === plant.water) : val););}` Do you mean : `... plant.[props])` ??

Comment: If you expect the state to contain an array, then `useState([])` is fine, but then you shouldn't be putting arbitrary key-value pairs onto that array, since it's an array, not a plain object. Maybe have a separate state as well? You also might name it `plants`, not `plant`, because it's a collection, not a single object.

Comment: `calculateValues` is just an example name for an external function that takes in the `plant` state, then calculates the values from it and the options by `.find`ing (essentially, what your effect hooks are doing now - except synchronously).

Comment: can I call it plants since I'm doing  setPlant(res.data.plants[0])? I I have const[plants, setPlants]=useState([]) then setPlant(res.data.plants[0]) would work fine ?

Comment: I don't see the dish state anywhere in your code, I'm only talking about the plant state - it's only the plant state that looks suspicious

Comment: ok, what about : `if (plant?.[prop]) {   setValues( values.map((val, j) => i === j ? options[i].find((t) => t.label === plant.water) : val););}` Do you mean : `... plant.[prop])` ?

Comment: Your original code had null checks with `plant?.water`, so that's the logic I copied. As I said in the answer, if the null checks aren't actually needed, it'd make more sense to get rid of them, yes. (but the proper syntax would be `plant[prop]`, not `plant.[prop]`)

Comment: Alright, I understand. Just to know what : where the options came from ?  I have `const SUN = [ { label: "Sunny", value: "sunny" },  ...   ];`, `const WATER = [ { label: "hydrate", value: "hydrate" },  ...   ];` etc

Comment: I don't know either, your [original code has things like `OPTION1` and `OPTION2` etc](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72419425/1), so that's what I copied - better to make those into a single array instead of having multiple standalone identifiers

Comment: Yes sorry, I've modified that. I've make those in a single array but it's not working, do you see why please ? : `const plantProperties = ['water', 'sun', 'date']; options=[SUN, WATER, DATE]  const [values, setValues] = useState(() => plantProperties.map(() => null));
    useEffect(() => {
        plantProperties.forEach((prop) => {
            if (plant?.[prop]) {
                setValues( values.map((val) => options.find((t) => t.label === plant[prop]) : val); ); } });}, [plant]);`

Comment: Order the `plantProperties` the same as `options` - eg `['water', 'sun', 'date']` with `[WATER, SUN, DATE]`. Also you have an extra semicolon causing a syntax error in the `setValues` call, and you also aren't checking the index of the value being iterated over to see if you need to replace it or not. Copy the code in my answer.

Comment: Alright, I've done the same as you told me : `const plantProperties = ['water', 'sun', 'date']; options=[ WATER, SUN, DATE] const [values, setValues] = useState(() => plantProperties.map(() => null));  useEffect(() => { plantProperties.forEach((prop, i) => { if (plant?.[prop]) { setValues( values.map((val, j) => i === j ? options[i].find((t) => t.label === plant[prop]) : val); ); }  });}, [plant]);` but how can I call these values in my `MyDrop` component please ? I've edited my question by adding my code

Comment: If you have a component that links itself to one of the options and one of the values, maybe you need a state for the selected option index too. `const [dropIndex, setDropIndex] = useState(0)` and then pass them down `<MyDrop options={options[dropIndex]} value={values[dropIndex]} setValue={makeSetValue(dropIndex)}` where `makeSetValue` takes the index and returns a function that sets the state of the value in the `values` array

Comment: I'm not sure to understand all you've written but I suspect my dropdown and label components to contain errors.Since react-select should contain change handler which is not the case...